# Array is empty in res.json() but it exists before and after the res.json() call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send a json response via Express through `res.json()`, but the value of the `records` in the object sent via `res.json()` is empty.

I have this block of code:

```
stats.activities(params).then(res => {
    processActivities(res, response => {
        console.log(response); // => logs response properly
        globalRes.json({
            ok: true,
            message: '',
            records: response // response is an empty array
        });
        console.log(response); // => logs response properly
    });
});
```

Here are my `console.logs()`:

```
[ players: [ [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ] ]
[ players: [ [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ] ]
```

And here is the response I am getting back (in Postman):

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "message": "",
    "records": []
}
```

Any idea as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Is it a real array (`Array.isArray(response)`)? Also, `processActivities` has a strange call signature: it calls a callback that doesn't adhere to the standard convention of `err, result`. Are you sure that you're calling it correctly?

Comment: @robertklep it is indeed a real array. Yeah, I called it right, it's my own function that I haven't implemented errors into yet.

Comment: What exactly does `response` contain? It seems to confuse `JSON.stringify()`, as it if either has no length, or it overloads `toJSON` or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a valid array:

```
[ players: [ [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ] ]
```

Arrays have numerical indexes, and a length. Your array has a property called `player`, which will be ignored when calling `JSON.stringify` on it.

Here's an example demonstrating the problem:

```
let a    = [];
a.player = 'jack';
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); // []
```

You probably want an object:

```
let a    = {};
a.player = 'jack';
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); // {"player":"jack"}
```

Comment: yeah, your comment above got me looking at it closer and I realized it. thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

What is globalRes? Normally you should use a response variable which is grabbed by the function on callback. You probably try to have some workaround, and probably your console.logs are executed after globalRes is actually sent.

Node is mostly async. Always keep this in mind.

Comment: `globalRes` is the express response object, and I'm getting a response with ok: true, message:'', and records being an empty array. so I don't think it's an issue with express ending the response.

Comment: So check what happens after. Something is obviously changing your response (either the "response" object, or globalRes). Use debugger, it will tell you what's happening.